# Variable initialization and declaration issue in java

Tags: java, initialization, declaration

When assigments are happening right to left,why following doesn't give compiler error?

```
String str = str = "";
```

Comment: why do you think is should give an error?

Comment: @ roni : caus I think the str (second one) has not been declared or initialized yet. There must be something wrong with me guys. And I wanna know what's that?

Comment: @ Jon : Yep Jon. That's my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is defined by the [Java Lanaguage Specification #15.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1-500) about the assignment operator. Namely (emphasis mine):

> Otherwise, three steps are required:
>
> - **First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable.** If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason; the right-hand operand is not evaluated and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the right-hand operand is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the value of the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the left-hand variable, is subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the variable.

So the evaluation of the expression `str = str = "";` is from right to left, but the left-hand operand `String str` is evaluated first and creates the variable.

Comment: Just to build on this... the variable reference for str is created first (String str) then the next part is evaluated - str=str in effect passing the now existing reference for str to str.  Then in the 3rd part you create a new String object ("" is equivelent to new String()) and then assign this to the reference for str.  So it is a perfectly valid scenario - although superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Java allows Objects to be assigned from right to left.

The following code clearly shows this.

```
String a;
String b;
String c;
String str = a = b = c = "Hello World!";
```

There is nothing like second str.

```
String str = str = ""; // There is only 1 str here and it is declared properly.Thus the compiler doesnt give any error.

String str = a = ""; // This will give Error Though since a is undeclared
```

Comment: Here you have declared a,b,c before str aren't you?

Comment: yes of course. We should declare the variables. JAVA only supports assignments in this fashion.

Comment: @ Byter : Yes Byter. But in my example, it looks like the second str has not been declared yet and you are going to assing "" to the second  str which has not been currently declared. Show me what's my wrong. and why?

Answer (score 0):

Compiler generates a warning for you `Assignment to variable str has no effect` which means compiler simply replacing it with

```
  String str = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [paragraph 6.3 of Java Language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) it is allowed to use a (local) variable within its own initializer.

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the
> rest of the block in which the declaration appears, **starting with
> its own initializer** and including any further declarators to the
> right in the local variable declaration statement.

It is not allowed to read a variable before it is initialized but that statement doesn't do that.